# what does the below code or solution mean

Tags: python, math, boolean

i search the web for answer and i manage to get the following codes to find the next Prime number. I understand the math part on part 1 of the code where it def the function to test if it is a Prime Number.

```
import math

def isPrime(num):
    if num == 1:
        return False
    square_root = int(math.sqrt(num))
    for i in range(2, square_root + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def nextPrime(currentPrime):
    flag = False#flag variable as a start, as false. Becomes a boonlean variable. #
    while flag == 0: #what the point of doing that?
        if currentPrime == 2: ##i guess the reason for doing that is because this is the first prime number
            currentPrime +=  1 ##so next prime number would essentially be 3, the only prime number sequence that is in the sequence, thus it is hard coded
        else:
            currentPrime +=  2  #whats the point of this?
        flag = isPrime(currentPrime) ##this as well
    return currentPrime ##i dont get it.

nextPrime(11)
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: the purpose of doing a flag variable. and assigning in at the end.

Comment: `flag = True` followed by `while flag == 0:` makes no sense. The `while` loop will never be entered.

Comment: hello B001, thanks for your help. My bad on the code as it should be Flag = False in the beginning. I was playing with it and testing it.
so given that flag = False at the start. and assume that at the end of the code, i input the currentPrime as 5 a Prime number, shouldnt it will become False = True ?

Comment: Sry Matthias, it was a typo there..

Comment: Do see my answer.Please consider using a debugger to understand the code execution. Let me know if you are still in doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some prime numbers

> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199

What can be seen is that they are all odd except `2` and they are also non-sequential numbers except 2 and 3.

So your question on `currentPrime +=  2` follows the principle that if given `11` for example the else block would increment by 2 since it will not have an adjacent number that can be odd. If it's 2 it increments by 1 since it can have an adjacent prime number 3. But this solution has issues, see below an example.

When you pass in `11` as the input, this block will execute on the first running

```
        else:
            currentPrime +=  2  #whats the point of this?
        flag = isPrime(currentPrime) ##this as well
    return currentPrime ##i dont get it.
```

and sets the flag variable to true since `13` is a prime number. This then returns that. `flag` variable is simply used to check if the number is a prime or not.

**It will not work on the following scenario**

What if you had passed in `12`? This will cause an infinite loop error because the same else block will increment by 2 meaning that is an even number and hence divisible.

To solve this change the else block to increment b `1` instead

```
        else:
            currentPrime +=  1
```

You should also consider using a vizualizer to understannd the execution of the code, see [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)